# How to gain access to all open windows on Desktop using Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

Is there a way to gain control over open windows on OS X desktop and change each window's properties i.e. size or location?

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging for this a while ago and found no real way to do it using Cocoa APIs. I think you may be able to use Carbon for this, but what I ended up using was the Cocoa-AppleScript Bridge to access the System Events AppleScript dictionary, which has objects representing application processes, windows of those processes, etc.